# checking multiple element state with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

currently I'm checking state of multiple elements using jquery like

```
if ($('#One').val() == 0 && $('#Two').val() == 0 && $('#Three').val() == 0){
   ...
}
```

In my real world code much more elements in this manner (up to 15) and I'm wondering is it possible to refactor this statement into something easier to overview?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give the elements with `id`s like `one/two/...` a general class and loop through them using this class (class name in my example `general_class`) :

```
var result = 0;

$('.general_class').each()
{
    if( $(this).val() != 0)
        result++;
}

if ( result == 0 ){
    //that mean all your inputs have 0 in value
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This answer is not right. If we have two inputs <input id="One" value="1"> <input id="Two" value="-1">, it will return true

Comment: You're totally right @DavidRissatoCruz, that why comments are helpful, thank you very much i learned something from you today (every day is a school day), check my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `Array.prototype.every()` . If added unique `class` to elements could use single selector , e.g., `$(".unique").get()`

```
var inputs = $("#One, #Two, #Three").get().every(function(el) {
  return el.value == 0
})
```

Comment: This is a elegant solution. However, he must be using ES6 in order to get it working. "Initial definition. Implemented in JavaScript 1.6." as we can check here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
 $('input').each(function(){
        if($(this).val()==0){
            alert("");


        }
    });
```

Comment: You can do just if(!$(this).val()) instead of if($(this).val()==0)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the cleanest way, but the most understandable and it works :

```
var toCheck = ['.Val1', '.Val2', '.Val3', '.Val4'];

var isOk = true;

$.each(toCheck, function(k, v){
    if($(v).val() == 0){
        isOk = false;
    }
});


if($isOk){
    // do whatever
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use `toArray()` then `every` with the [arrow expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every#Using_arrow_functions):-

```
if($("#One, #Two, #Three").toArray().every(el => el.value == 0)){
   //All zero
}
```

**Example**

```js
function check() {
  if ($("#One, #Two, #Three").toArray().every(el => el.value == 0)) {
    $('<div>All Zero</div>').insertAfter('#check');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='One' type="text" value="0" />
<input id='Two' type="text" value="0" />
<input id='Three' type="text" value="0" />
<input type="button" id="check" value="check" onclick="check()">
```

Comment: I'm getting syntax error on =>  Though this expression works,  error is in vs.

Answer (score 0):

I assume what you want is ensure all your input fields have value zero (at least is what I could understand from your code).

You could create a class or a custom property for each element, like that:

```
<input name="value1" data-must-be-zero>
<input name="value2" data-must-be-zero>
```

and you could select:

```
var myInputs = $("input[data-must-be-zero]");
var allRight = myInputs.filter( function() { return $(this).val() != 0; }).length === 0;
```